# Can not connect to some ports on Local Area Network

Tags: port, connection, lan, web

I have 2 PCs connected by a switch.
PC1--<-->--Switch--<-->--PC2

Both PCs have Windows 7.
Both are able to connect and share files with each other.
Both PCs can connect via remote desktop.
Firewall is disabled on both PCs.
But I can not connect from PC1 to the web server in PC2 on port 80.
PC2 has proxy server runnin on port 8888.
I can connect to port 8888 by sockets from PC1 but I can't connect to port 80. Connection timeouts...

What can be the problem and how can be solved?

**EDIT: NETSTAT Output of PC2 (netstat -anb):**

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:809            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:990            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  WcesComm
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  eventlog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1029           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1037           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [services.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2383           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [msmdsrv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  CryptSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    127.0.0.1:21           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:23           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:25           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:110          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:143          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:554          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:808          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1434         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [sqlservr.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5679         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  WcesComm
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7438         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  WcesComm
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8010         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8110         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:21         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:23         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:25         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:110        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    192.168.2.3:143        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:554        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:1080       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:2080       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:7000       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:8010       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:8080       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    192.168.2.3:8110       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [WinGate.exe]
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:554               [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  TCP    [::]:990               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  WcesComm
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:1025              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    [::]:1026              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  eventlog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:1027              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:1029              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    [::]:1037              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [services.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2383              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [msmdsrv.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2869              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  CryptSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:3587              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  p2pimsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:10243             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::1]:1434             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [sqlservr.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:5679             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  WcesComm
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:445  [fe80::c79:b496:f8cc:7d1b%23]:1121  ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:1034  [fe80::c79:b496:f8cc:7d1b%23]:1029  ESTABLISHED
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:1051  [fe80::c79:b496:f8cc:7d1b%23]:3587  ESTABLISHED
  p2pimsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:1054  [fe80::c79:b496:f8cc:7d1b%23]:3587  TIME_WAIT
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:520            *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3544           *:*                    
  iphlpsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5004           *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5005           *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51148          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55535          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55834          *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55836          *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55838          *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59370          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:65467          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:65468          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:53           *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:368          *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:8000         *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:55627        *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:53         *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:67         *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:137        *:*                    
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    192.168.2.3:138        *:*                    
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    192.168.2.3:368        *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:1900       *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:8000       *:*                    
 [WinGate.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:51174      *:*                    
  iphlpsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    192.168.2.3:55626      *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3540              *:*                    
  p2pimsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                    
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5004              *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5005              *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:55835             *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:55837             *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:55839             *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::1]:55625            *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:546  *:*                    
  Dhcp
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:1900  *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::adb8:8865:e549:ec5d%23]:55624  *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
```

Comment: Can PC2 connect to its web server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1)?

Comment: PC2 web server is probably listening to `127.0.0.1:80` only.

Comment: Yes PC2 can connect to it's web server.

Comment: @Steve-o: Web servers listen to port only. It looks like the port is closed for external connections (but firewall is disabled)... The PC2 has WinGate installed if it will help.

Comment: output of netstat -an on PC2? (Add it to the question)

Comment: @EightBitTony: here it is.

Comment: So on that output there's nothing listening on port 8888 - so there's definitely some confusion somewhere, are you sure you're connecting to PC2.

Comment: port 8888 is WinGete proxy and yes i'm connecting. i'm also connecting with remote desktop and normal windows network file sharing... can this be because of the web site's folder to not have enough permissions?

Comment: @Samet Before check if there is a problem with the web server, from PC1 install the technet client and run: telnet PC2 80. This is for test if there is communication by the TCP port. Add the result to your question.

Add what web server you are running.

Change the output of the netstat -an of your question for one of netstat -anb that is for can see what application is on each port 80. Thank you.

Comment: sorry the proxy runs on port 8080 not 8888...

telnet on port 80: Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed.

telnet on port 8080: No error. It connects. I can issue proxy commands.

There is IIS 7.5 on PC2 as a web server.